# Modify regex to match dates with ordinals "st", "nd", "rd", "th"

Tags: regex, date, ordinals

How can the regex below be modified to match dates with ordinals on the day part? This regex matches "Jan 1, 2003 | February 29, 2004 | November 02, 3202" but I need it to match also: "Jan 1st, 2003 | February 29th, 2004 | November 02nd, 3202 | March 3rd, 2010"

```
^(?:(((Jan(uary)?|Ma(r(ch)?|y)|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Oct(ober)?|Dec(ember)?)\ 31)|((Jan(uary)?|Ma(r(ch)?|y)|Apr(il)?|Ju((ly?)|(ne?))|Aug(ust)?|Oct(ober)?|(Sept|Nov|Dec)(ember)?)\ (0?[1-9]|([12]\d)|30))|(Feb(ruary)?\ (0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8]|(29(?=,\ ((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))))))\,\ ((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))
```

Thank you.

Comment: Ma(r(ch)?|y) will match Mary, is it desired behaviour? :)

Comment: Igor, no, it won't. The pipe is between the whole of "r(ch)?" and "y". It will either match "r", "rch" or "y".

Comment: English only yes. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will depend on your use case, but in the interest of pragmatism, you might do well to just match anything matching:
(1) any month name or abbreviation;
(2) whitespace;
(3) any one or two digits;
<strike>(4) whitespace;</strike>
(5) any st,nd,rd,th;
(6) whitespace OR comma + optional whitespace;
(7) any four digits;

I'm not sure what you're matching in, but if I had `Jan 35nd,3001`, I think I'd rather **capture it now and invalidate it later** than to just skip over it right at the get-go.

Also, depending on your data set, consider case sensitivity issues and common international English variants, like `1 Jan 2004` or `1st Jan, 2004` or `January, 2004` etc.

*line breaks added*

```
^(?:j(?:an(?:uary)?|un(?:e)?|ul(?:y)?)?|feb(?:ruary)?|ma(?:r(?:ch)?|y)
|a(?:pr(?:il)?|ug(?:ust)?)|sep(?:t|tember)?|oct(?:ober)?|(?:nov|dec)(?:ember)?)  
\s+\d{1,2}(?:st|nd|rd|th)?(?:\s+|,\s*)\d{4}\b
```

Even more pragmatic (and *readable*), unless you have a very bizarre dataset, is to allow anything after the common prefixes:

```
(?:jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)[a-z]*?\s+\d{1,2}(?:[a-z]{2})?(?:\s+|,\s*)\d{4}\b
```

Would this match `octagenarianism     99xx,           0000` ? Yes. Is that likely to be an issue? I doubt it.

Comment: I agree with you. I know nothing about regex so I had to rely on a sample I had found. I tested your sample against http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx and it couldn't match January 20, 2020.

Comment: Sorry, some perl regex metacharacters snuck in there. I've edited it to match .NET flavour.

Comment: Very sensible.  I just have one quibble: you list `(4) whitespace;` *between* the digits and the ordinal suffix.  That doesn't really belong there--and I notice it's not reflected in your regexes, either.

Comment: You're right, Alan. Cut-and-paste editing gone awry ("Foiling computer users since 1974").

Answer (score 2):

That regex is doing waaaaay too much. You'd be much better off using your language's equivalent of `strptime()`. However, the regex below will match ordinals:

```
^(?:(((Jan(uary)?|Ma(r(ch)?|y)|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Oct(ober)?|Dec(ember)?)\ 31(st)?)|((Jan(uary)?|Ma(r(ch)?|y)|Apr(il)?|Ju((ly?)|(ne?))|Aug(ust)?|Oct(ober)?|(Sept|Nov|Dec)(ember)?)\ (0?[1-9]|([12]\d)|30))(st|nd|rd|th)?|(Feb(ruary)?\ (0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8]|(29(th)?(?=,\ ((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))))(st|nd|rd|th)?))\,\ ((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))
```

Note that it will also match things like "20nd" but the likelihood of encountering that in real data is way too low to bother caring in most cases.

Comment: While I like your answer and it works, I picked Jay's regex since it was smaller. I wish I could select both as correct.