# Modify regex to match dates with ordinals “st”, “nd”, “rd”, “th”

Tags: regex

I've see the the answer for the question at : [Modify regex to match dates with ordinals "st", "nd", "rd", "th"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118825/modify-regex-to-match-dates-with-ordinals-st-nd-rd-th)
But I need it in Perl format.

Also this only parse Jan 1st, 2004. I need a regex that can parse 1 jan 2004, 1st Jan 2004 or 1st of Jan 2004. Im very new to regex so have no idea how to get this.

This is only for english dates and it will need to be for Jan / January.

Any information will help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
my @strs = ('1 jan 2004','1st Jan 2004','1st of Jan 2004');
for(@strs)
{
   if(m/^\s*(\d+)(?:[a-z]{2})?\s+(?:of\s+)?([a-z]{3})\s+(\d{4})/i)
   {
        my($date,$month,$year) = ($1,$2,$3);
        print "matched $date $month $year\n";
   }
}
```

This doesn't validate the strings are valid dates (ie 43rd of Jan), but that checking could
be added with the $date, $month, $year variables.